# How can I get my SATA DVDs working again?

Tags: windows-7, raid, dvd, sata

My hard drive crashed (WinXPpro), so I took a C drive from a broken PC.  The new C drive is Win7pro.  Motherboard is **MSI K8N Neo4 Platinum**, with 4 hard drives installed on SATA 1-4 (**nForce4 Ultra**); the two DVD drives are loaded on **SATA 7-8 (Silicon Image SATARAID5)**.  I've tweaked BIOS settings every which way. The closest thing to success was when each DVD had both a CD and a DVD icon, and blinked green.  No CD or DVD could be read in either drive.

I assume that the problem resulted from the fact that my new C drive does not have the RAID drivers?  I've tried loading from the floppy (doesn't work).  I can't boot off the DVD/CD, and switching the DVD's SATA cable to the SATA 3 slot (and pulling one of the hard discs) didn't work.

I'd like to be able to use the other two available SATA slots for a mirrored RAID drive, and get my DVDs working again.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you just plug in the "new" hard drive and try to start up? That usually isn't a good way to do it. It is from a different system setup. you need to install with the system configuration you have in your current box. I'm sure if you do a clean install you will be fine.

Comment: How can I do that when my DVD drive doesn't work?  I can't boot off the DVD to the installation disc in order to do a clean install...

Comment: ok here try this. Disable the raid setup in Bios. I do believe you need to install windows first and then install the raid drivers after install. then restart to bios and set your raid up again. I think that is how I did it when I built my box. At least if you go back to regular setup it should make your dvd work again.